JAVA Spring calling a Stored Procedure expects 3 parameters when there should only be 2
my repository is as following:
@Repository
public interface StatisticsRepository  extends JpaRepository<CampaignStatisticModel, Integer> {

    @Procedure(value = "getCampaignStatistics")
    CampaignStatisticModel getCampaignStatistics(@Param("guid") String guid, @Param("accountCode") String accountCode);

}

who calls the below stored MariaDB procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE `getCampaignStatistics`(IN p_Guid VARCHAR(255), IN p_AccountCode VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  [ select some data and return resultset ]
END

The Entity is as follows:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class CampaignStatisticModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3755864725693749052L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer id;
    
    private String accountCode;
    
    private String guid;
    
    private String name;

    private Long totalContacts;
    
    private Long totalProcessed;
    
}

When using MariaDB command line, the stored procedure works perfectly and returns a resultset with some rows.
But when calling the procedure in my JAVA Spring REST API :
CampaignStatisticModel csm = repository.getStatisticsRepository().getCampaignStatistics(guid, accountCode);

It fails returning NULL.
Logs show this:
2024-04-03 23:31:29.109 DEBUG 22480 -- [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [] org.hibernate.SQL                       .logStatement 94  : 
    {call getCampaignStatistics(?,?,?)}
Hibernate: 
    {call getCampaignStatistics(?,?,?)}
2024-04-03 23:31:29.232  WARN 22480 -- [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  .logExceptions 137  : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
2024-04-03 23:31:29.234 ERROR 22480 -- [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  .logExceptions 142  : Parameter index of 3 is out of range (1, 2)

Why is the stored procedure call expecting 3 parameters when the procedure only accepts 2???
Why is csm (CampaignStatisticModel model), which is meant to be populated by the resultset, is always NULL?
Additional screenshot from dbForge:

Note: Using Spring Boot 5.1.8 and Mariadb 10.5.23
Thanks in advance!

Are you sure you're connecting to the same database? Could it be your app is connecting to a database with an earlier version of the SP?

Share us a reproducible sample, just to validate if you are using another database

@Bohemian yes, I am sure. There is only 1 database, and the SP is brand new, haven't had more than 2 parameters.

just added a screenshot from dbForge with some details of the SP

I made multiple tests using the code described in my original post, but all would result in the same issue: hibernate would call the SP with 3 parameter, even when the SP only expects 2 parameters!
This is stupid, and I could not understand why the issue happens! Maybe a bug in hibernate?? who knows? ...
So, I kind of solved the issue by modifying the repository with the following lines:
@Query(value = "CALL getCampaignStatistics(:guid, :accountCode)", nativeQuery = true)
    CampaignStatisticModel getCampaignStatistics(String guid, String accountCode);

Instead of using the @Procedure annotation, I implemented a @Query as a nativeQuery.
